# junit assume command - can i put it inside setup method to ignore all tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit4

I have a set of test cases and i would like the entire file ignored if some condition is met.  Can i use 
`Assume.assumeTrue(precondition);` in the setup method to ensure that if a precondition is false that the test will not run in the entire file?

so if i had a setup method like this:

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
     Assume.assumeTrue(1==3);//entire test file should be ignored is my hope
       //some setup stuff ...
    }
```

can i hope that none of my test will run ? this is my end goal that on some condition being met i can ignore all tests in a file. I have tried it and it seems to ignore them but want a expert opinion and i dont want the Assume method to affect any other tests besides the one in the file its called in.

Comment: Will you put a conditional to your tests? Why?

Comment: i need one because im working with another team who do not want my test. we have a build flag set up so know if its my team or his team and it should ignore the test if its the other team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I thinking it is not a good practice, I can understand the `@Ignore` annotation to put some Tests in quarantine. But I am not sure about conditioning it to a flag.

That said, implement this: 
https://gist.github.com/yinzara/9980184

Then use this `@ConditionalIgnore` annotation.

```
public class SomeTest {
  @Rule
  public ConditionalIgnoreRule rule = new ConditionalIgnoreRule();

  @Test
  @ConditionalIgnore( condition = IgnoredByTeamA.class )
  public void testIgnoredByTeamA() {
       ...
  }
}

public class IgnoredByTeamA implements IgnoreCondition {
  public boolean isSatisfied() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

More details [here](http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/11/18/a-junit-rule-to-conditionally-ignore-tests/)

Comment: Do you know which package i have to import to get IgnoreCondition to be recognized class.

Comment: To be honest, I think is not a good Idea. You need to hack the JUnit... Have you looked the link?

Comment: Yes i read the link. But where is the interface declaration. I can't find the package. I might have to stick with Assume. I see your update on the gist. Looks scary

Comment: Yep... it is, but if you notice in the bottom. It uses Assume.assertTrue under the hood.